# If initial condition gives $\dot{x_i}=0$ then $x_i$ is constant for all $t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This is probably a silly question but I am struggling to get my head around it.

Suppose I have the $2D$ system $\dot{x}=1-y(1+x)$, $\dot{y}=y(y-1)(1+2x^2+y^2)$. Here $x,y$ are both functions of $s\in(-\infty,\infty)$.

Clearly if $y=0$ at $s=0$ then $\dot{y}=0$ at $s=0$. But how can I show that, given this condition $y(0)=0$, that $y(s)=0$ for all $s<0$ and $s>0$?

All I can think to do is Taylor expand $y(0±s_0)$. If I can show that $\frac{d^ny}{ds^n}$ vanishes at $s=0$ for $n\geq2$ then this approach would work, but I am struggling to come up with a suitable induction hypothesis for this. I am guessing there is a much simpler approach?

Comment: Do you know [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)?

Comment: "Clearly if $y=0$ at $s=0$ then $\dot{y}=0$ at $s=0$"? This is incorrect. For example, for $y=s$, $y(0)=0$, but $y'(0)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be clear from the equations that
$$x(s)=s+a,\,\, y(s)=0$$
is a solution to the system with initial values $x(0)=a$, $y(0)=0$. Are there some uniqueness theorems you could apply to this system? If you the know the solution is unique for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$ then any solution for which $y(0)=0$ is of the above form and $y(s)=0$ for all $s$.

Comment: I can use Picard-Lindelöf, but doesn't this only tell me that the above solution is true for some $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ and not necessarily the whole real line?

Comment: Also, a follow-up question if you don't mind. (I want to know if I can prove the same sort of thing without actually knowing the solution $x(t)$). Say I have the more generic system $\dot{x}=f(x,y), \dot{y}=(y-b)g(x,y)$ and I know that $(x(0),y(0))=(a,b)$, and that $f,g\in C^1$. Since $y(t)=b$ solves the $\dot{y}$ part and $\dot{x}=f(x,b)$ has a unique solution $\tilde{x}(t)$ by Picard-Lindelöf, does this mean $x=\tilde{x}(t)$ and $y=b$ is the unique solution here?

Comment: Picard-Lindelof tells you that there exists a unique solution defined in a neighborhood of $0$. It just so happens we can explicitly find the solution, and it is globally defined.